# How do I return an HTTP response in a callback in Flask, or does it even matter?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, flask

I am familiar with evented servers but not threaded ones. A common feature of REST APIs implemented in evented systems like node.js+express or tornado is, in an handler, to do some I/O work asynchronously in a callback, then return the actual HTTP response *in the callback*.  In Express, we have things like:

```
app.post('/products', function (req, res) {
  Product.create(req.body, function (err, product) {
    if (err) return res.json(400, err);
    res.send(201, product);
  });
});
```

where `Post.create` hits the database and calls the callback after the product is persisted. The response, whether 201 or 400 is sent in the callback.  This keeps the server freed up to do other things while the database is working, but from the point of view of the client, the request seems to take a while.

Suppose I wanted to do the same thing in Flask (which is not an evented server).  If I have a POST handler to create several objects that needs to make several database writes that could take several seconds to complete, it seems I have two choices:

1. I could immediately return a 202 ACCEPTED but then this burdens the client with having to check back to see whether all the writes were committed.
2. I could just implement all the database writes directly inside the handler. The client will have to wait the few seconds for the reply, but it's synchronous and simple from the client perspective.

My question is whether if I do #2, is Flask smart enough to block the current request thread so that other requests can be handled during the database writes?  I would hope the server doesn't block here.

BTW I have done long polling, but this is for a public REST API where clients expect simple requests and responses, so I think either approach 1 or 2 is best.  Option 1 seems rare to me, but I am worried about #2 blocking the server?  Am I right to be concerned, or is Flask (and threaded servers) just smart so I need not worry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Blocking vs. non-blocking

Flask itself (much like express) is not inherently blocking or non-blocking - it relies on the underlying container to provide the features necessary for operation (reading data from the user and writing responses to the user).  If the server does not provide an event loop (e. g. mod_wsgi) then Flask will block.  If the server is a non-blocking one (e. g. gunicorn) then Flask will *not* block.

On the other end of things, if the code that you write in your handlers is blocking Flask will block, *even if it is run on a non-blocking container*.

Consider the following:

```
app.post('/products', function (req, res) {
  var response = Product.createSync(req.body);
  // Event loop is blocked until Product is created
  if (response.isError) return res.json(400, err);
  res.send(201, product);
});
```

If you run that on a node server you will quickly bring everything to a screeching halt. Even though node itself is non-blocking your code is not and it blocks the event loop *preventing you from handling **any** other request from this node until the loop is yielded at `res.json` or `res.send`*.  Node's ecosystem makes it easy to find non-blocking IO libraries - in most other common environments you have to make a conscious choice to use non-blocking libraries for the IO you need to do.

#### Threaded servers and how they work

Most non-evented containers use multiple threads to manage the workload of a concurrent system.  The container accepts requests in the main thread and then farms off the *handling* of the request and the serving of the response to one of its worker threads.  The worker thread executes the (most often blocking) code necessary to handle the request and generate a response.  While the handling code is running that thread is blocked and cannot take on any other work.  If the request rate exceeds the total thread pool count then clients start backing up, waiting for a thread to complete.

#### What's the best thing to do with a long-running request in a threaded environment?

Knowing that blocking IO blocks one of your workers, the question now is "how many concurrent users are you expecting to have?" (Where concurrent means "occur over the span of time it takes to accept and process one request")  If the answer is "less than the total number of threads in my worker thread pool" then you are golden - your server can handle the load and it's non-blocking nature is in no way a threat to stability.  Choosing between #1 and #2 is largely a matter of taste.

On the other hand, if the answer to the above question is "more than the total number of works in my thread pool" then you will need to handle the requests by passing off the user's data to another worker pool (generally via a queue of some kind) and responding to the request with a `202` (Option #1 in your list).  That will enable you to lower the response time, which will, in turn, enable you to handle more users.

#### TL;DR

- Flask is not blocking or non-blocking as it does no *direct* IO
- Threaded servers block on the request / response handling thread, not the accept request thread
- Depending on the expected traffic you will almost certainly want to go go with option #1 (return a 202 and push the work into a queue to be handled by a different thread pool / evented solution).

Comment: Note that while *Flask* does no direct IO, the underlying Werkzeug library *does* do direct IO when it receives a file larger than a certain size (it writes it to disk rather than keeping it in memory).  This is done using Python's `write`, which is sync and blocking.  So, in the case of accepting large files at least, Werkzeug will block (unless you disable that functionality or monkey-patch it).